# When using JFileChooser with PDFBox, the file does not save as a pdf but it saves with no extension

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, pdfbox

When the JFileChooser is called, the file that is saved and the result is not a pdf. To put in better words, I call JFileChooser and save it with some name. Then when i go to that location, the file does not have the .pdf extension, I tried using .getName() and then adding the .pdf extension to it and setting that equal to .getName() but that does not work. How do I fix this?

I made a JavaFX project for this, and the window on there just displays a button that when clicked the method "methodActivate" is called.

```
package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("\\Pdfbox.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,300);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    public void methodActivate() throws IOException{

         PDDocument doc = 
         new PDDocument();
            doc.addPage(new PDPage());
            boolean bool = false;
            try{
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                  doc.save(file);
                  doc.close();
                }
                doc.close();
            } catch (Exception io){
                System.out.println(io);
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify, please? The title of your question contradicts the body of your question.

Comment: how does it contradict? I edited to try to clarify but i dont know how it contradicts

Comment: getName() returns only the name after the last "/", that is why it didn't work.

Comment: Use getAbsolutePath() instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `JFileChooser` with JavaFX anyway. Use a [JavaFX `FileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) instead.

Comment: @RahulShah if the answer was helpful, don't forget to click the green checkmark :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter a name in the JFileChooser window like "myPdf" without the .pdf, then it will save it with that name. 
JFileChooser doesn't append file types automatically, so if that's something you need then you can check for it

```
public File checkFileName(File file) {
    if (!file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
        return new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".pdf");
    } else {
        return file;
    }
}
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for more information about JFileChooser

Comment: you meant to write "new File" instead of "new file". I'd also suggest to add ".tolower()" in the second line. And getName() isn't the correct method, better use getAbsolutePath(). Besides that, the answer is fine.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You're right thank you, I have edited with those suggestions and grammar fix